# PHP Check If require_once() Content Is Empty

Tags: php, include, server-side-includes, require-once

I am working on a PHP script which involves me including several external PHP scripts via the "require_once()" method. I would like to know if there is a way for the master script (the one including the others) to tell whether or not the **processed output** from included script has generated any content.

So, for example, maybe the user's permissions for a particular script results in PHP not generating any output. So, maybe, the master script would echo something like:

```
                             Nothing interesting here!
```

Is there a way to do that in the master script, or would I need to create these tests inside of the included script, and return the results to the master script?

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Comment: You will first have to process the script, to check if return is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can capture the output using [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start), [`ob_get_contents`](http://php.net/ob_get_contents) and [`ob_end_clean`](http://php.net/ob_end_clean) like this:

```
ob_start();
require_once('script.php');
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ob_start();
require_once 'your_file.php';
$output = ob_get_flush(); // ob_get_clean() if you want to suppress the output

if(empty($output)) {
    echo 'Nothing interesting here!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry if the require_once is executed on not. Try to identify if the variables/functions of require_once files are working or not by using the debug function like this:-

```
var_dump($Your_Variable_Name_from_require_Once_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can also use:

```
@$result = include $filename;
```

include does return false when the file can't be found, but it does also generate a warning. That's why you need the @.

I was tempted to use file_exists() however as noted in a comment in php docs, file_exists() DOESN'T SEARCH THE PHP INCLUDE_PATH and the results of this function are cached.

So if you decided to use file_exists() then you will want to probably use clearstatcache() that being the case you may want to have a look here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php#125163

and here :

[clearstatcache + include_path + sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251237/clearstatcache-include-path-sessions)