# Cpanel cronjob not working

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cron-task

I have a php script in root of my site. I have added a cronjob in my cpanel.
It is working with basic database operations like shown below:

```
<?php
require_once "classes/class.database.php";
$db = new database;
$db->connectToDB();
$data = date("Y/m/d H:i");
$res = $db->insertRow("cron",array("datetime"),array($data));
echo $res;
?>
```

In same file I have replaced these codes with codes below which are real codes  that I want to schedule but it is not working. If I enter manually, it works but by this way it doesnt working.

Real Codes:

```
<?php
require_once "/home/domain/subdomain.domain.com/share/share.php";
$share = new share;
$share->sharePosts();
?>
```

I dont think there is an error in my code because it works manually however I want to be sure about that. Can I log output of this file? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: turn on error reporting, `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: Check if the require is working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560751/php-check-if-require-once-content-is-empty

Comment: when I simply just echo something, it mails to me the output but if there is an error it doesn't.

Comment: What's the exact cron job that you added?

Comment: Thank you all, I have solved issue. It was about "required" places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the issue. 
I have enabled error logging with codes below.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
```

I have tried to mail myself (it is cpanels property) and just echo something.
Mail came succesfully. Then I wrote wrong code (I wrote wrong path to "required_once"), when I execute manually, gives fatal error. Fatal errors not mailed. After that I replaced "require_once" with "include" to avoid fatal errors, then it noticed an error but this time it mailed to me. Error was "No such file." Then I tried path like that "/home/domain.com/yourcron.php" and no errors. In conclusion, all paths must be like "/home/domain.com/yourcron.php".